# Why are AWS CLI not working from behind a IPv6 address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have problems using AWS CLI from an IPv6 address on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.
Simple commands like `aws lambda get-account-settings` run idle indefinitely.
When switching to an IPv4 address, everythings works fine.

Same behavior when using Python's boto3 library.

Any ideas?

Comment: give a read to this article, lambda does not support ipv6.l, it list various other services which support and doest not support ipv6.https://cloudonaut.io/getting-started-with-ipv6-on-aws/

Comment: How did it go. Is is still unclear why ipv6 does not work for lambda?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I understand now that IPv6 is not supported for Lambda. Let's hope this changes in the future. For now, I will stick to a workaround and access the lambda functionality from an IPv4 device when needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/lambda-service.html) service **does not have IPv6** (dual-stack) endpoints. Only some services in some regions support IPv6, such as [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/dual-stack-endpoints.html#dual-stack-endpoints-cli) or [EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Using_Endpoints.html#ipv6).

Even if they support IPv6 you have to make **extra settings** to use this as explained in the linked docs for S3 and EC2.

Answer (score 1):

[Lambda now has IPv6 endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/aws-lambda-ipv6-endpoints-inbound-connections/) as of early December 2021. It joins the list of about 8-10 AWS services which *do* support IPv6 (depending on how you count).

So for example:

```
aws lambda list-functions --endpoint https://lambda.us-west-2.api.aws
```

If you are also looking for other services, I have [a blog post here](https://danopia.net/posts/2021/aws-endpoints-with-ipv6.html) showing all APIs with known IPv6-capable endpoints. Realistically speaking though, IPv4 will be necessary to interact with most AWS services for some time. If you are just trying to not interact with the IPv4 Internet, [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints.html) can help get internal IPv4s for many AWS services.